# org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException:

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am getting below error when I run my script.

> org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied
>   data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part
>   of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a
>   different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)

My code:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.Status;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.testng.Assert;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;

public class test1 extends baset {

@Test
public void ddtest() throws IOException {

        test = extent.createTest("captureScreenshotTest");
        File file = TestDataFile();
        HSSFCell Expectedprofilename;
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("ss");
        int TotalRow;
        int TotalCol;
        TotalRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        TotalCol = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
        HSSFRow headerRow = sheet.getRow(0);

}
```

}

package com.examplesite.base;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
public class SuperClass {

    public static File TestDataFile() {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\mm\\seleniumTestdata.xlsx");
        return file;

    }


}
```

POM

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.17-beta1</version>
 </dependency>
```

---

Update

I changed the test to this:

```
@Test
public void ddtest() throws IOException {

    test = extent.createTest("captureScreenshotTest");


    File file = TestDataFile();

    XSSFCell Expectedprofilename;
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("mm");
    int TotalRow;
    int TotalCol;

    TotalRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    TotalCol = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();

    XSSFRow headerRow = sheet.getRow(0);

}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.util.POILogger.log(ILjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.apache.poi.util.DocumentHelper.trySetXercesSecurityManager(DocumentHelper.java:84)
    at org.apache.poi.util.DocumentHelper.<clinit>(DocumentHelper.java:57)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ContentTypeManager.parseContentTypesFile(ContentTypeManager.java:376)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ContentTypeManager.<init>(ContentTypeManager.java:102)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipContentTypeManager.<init>(ZipContentTypeManager.java:54)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:194)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:684)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:275)
    at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:274)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
```

---

Update

```
I was able to fix this error by adding same version dependencies. 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.17-beta1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.17-beta1</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: Did you try the suggested change in the error message and change your HSSF references to XSSF? It might be as simple as that.

Comment: I changed to XSSF. Now I get different error.

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:selenium-webdriver]?

Comment: I assume you also changed the imports?  Is it working now?

Comment: Yes, imports were also changed. It is working.